# download a file with the '+' character in it's name

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm dealing with a C# web system that has a feature of uploading and downloading files. Some of those files happen to have the '+' character in their names or folders.

I figured out that '+' is problematic in URL's as it represents concatenation and the plus character should be encoded as %2b.

So I tried to set `newUrl =url.string.Replace("+", "%2b")` and then to do:

```
System.Net.WebClient req = new System.Net.WebClient();
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
byte[] buffer = req.DownloadData(newUrl);
```

Which ended up with a download failure and application exception message

> "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

In addition, attempting to access the file from the browser, either as 
http://repository.mysite.figure+numbers.pdf or
http://repository.mysite.figure%2bnumbers.pdf
ends up with error 404.

It seems like there is no way out. looking for the file "draw%2bnumbers.pdf" would fail as it doesn't exists, but on the other hand "draw+numbers.pdf" would fail too as there is no "drawnumbers.pdf".

Is there any solution to this problem except renaming all of the files and folders in the repository?

Comment: `draw+numbers` would result in `draw numbers` - a raw `+` in a URL is treated as a space.  Can you show the actual URL (without any encoding) that you want to download, ie one that works if you copy/paste into a browser?

Comment: Did you try encoding using [HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of manually replacing characters?

Comment: showing the full URL here won't help as accessing it requires an account with user and password. Sorry.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Wouldn't it only do that in the query string portion of an URL?

Comment: @Joey Not sure now you mention it, you may well be right.  OP - You can instead show something with an "anonymised" url, such as "example.com/my+file.pdf" - it's not entirely clear what the full URL of the file you're trying to retrieve is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution to this. Check this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/URLs+with+a+Plus+Character+Trigger+a+404+Error+When+Using+an+IIS+Reverse+Proxy+Server).

IIS doesnot allow double escaping by default which stops the **+** character to go correctly in URL.

**ANSWER UPDATED :**

We need to add `<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />` in the security section of the webconfig and reset IIS once to make it work. 
Like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is there a web.config for IIS itself, or do you mean the app web.config?

Comment: @niry: It worked. Took me a while to find where is that web.config to edit, but once
I found it it did the trick. Thanks.